# MacOS has recently become messed up

Tags: macos, resolution, updates, notifications

I've recently been noticing that my OS has been a bit buggy lately, especially my notification.. They doesn't appear in the upper right corner as before but seem to appear in the middle of the screen...

Like this:

[image: notification window popup]

And even the notification sound of the Mail app and notification window is very much out of sync, The is outputted sound first,and the window after ~5 seconds delay.

I also noticed that the window size of the logon screen is significantly smaller than it was before..

[image: logon window]

What is wrong with it?
I tried rebooting, multiple times but nothing changes.. ?

Hardware specs:

[Hardware specs:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFDVy.png)

Comment: What hardware are you using? What version of the operating system? Anything that you've recently done that could've caused it?

Comment: Added hardware specs.. Not sure what it could be.. I guess updating but that it?

Comment: You're up-to-date, I think. Try [resetting the NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) and see if that helps.

Comment: it seems to have fixed... now its just the audio sync that is a problem